# How to use f-string formatting around a string of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

The following code causes an Invalid Format Specifier when the string is converted to an f-string. I can't pinpoint what the problem is as my quotations look okay.

```
expected_document = f'{"name":"tenders","value":"chicken","key":"{key}"}'
```

causes:

```
>       expected_document = f'{"name":"tenders","value":"chicken","key":"{key}"}'
E       ValueError: Invalid format specifier
```

while removing the `f`:

```
expected_document = '{"name":"tenders","value":"chicken","key":"{key}"}'
```

works fine.

Comment: Why are you using an f-string at all? Does the "works fine" example give you the result you want? Or is that `key` the only thing you want interpolated?

Comment: Also when using string formatting, double up the brackets to escape them. Ex: `{` should be `{{` if you want it escaped.

Comment: I need expected_document to be a string where {key} is a variable surrounded by double quotes.

Answer (score 7):

Why use *f-string* at all?

The following code works.

```
key = 'test'

expected_document = { "name": "tenders", "value": "chicken", "key": key }

print(expected_document)
```

*Output:*

```
{'name': 'tenders', 'value': 'chicken', 'key': 'test'}
```

---

**Update #1:** If you want it as a string and don't want to do type conversion, then...

```
key = 'test'

expected_document_1 = '{"name":"tenders","value":"chicken","key":"' + key + '"}'  # old fashioned way

print(expected_document_1)

expected_document_2 = f'{{"name":"tenders","value":"chicken","key":"{key}"}}'  # using f-string

print(expected_document_2)
```

*Output:*

```
{"name":"tenders","value":"chicken","key":"test"}
{"name":"tenders","value":"chicken","key":"test"}
```

---

**Update #2:** [@Error - Syntactical Remorse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8150685/error-syntactical-remorse) had already suggested the second option of escaping the braces in one of the comments.

Comment: Because I need expected_document to be a string, I'm asserting it equals another string where key could change. Maybe it's possible I could change types of that string to a dictionary or something?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just put the f inside the dict like this:

```
key = 'test'

expected_document = {"name":"tenders","value":"chicken","key":f"{key}"}
```

Comment: I do need expected_document to be a string, thanks for replying!

Comment: just put str(expected_document) afterwards

Comment: You don't need to use f-string in your example. `expected_document = {"name": "tenders", "value": "chicken", "key": key}` will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could compile the dictionary without using interpolation and then convert it to a string.

```py
temporary_variable = {"name": "tenders", "value": "chicken", "key": key}
expected_document = str(temporary_variable)
```

Or you could even put this in one line.

```py
expected_document = str({"name": "tenders", "value": "chicken", "key": key})
```

I am using Python 3.6.3 - I don't know how other versions would handle this. A potential drawback of this is that you shouldn't rely on dictionaries to maintain their order, which could cause this to break.